# Inventory Management System Application in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, inventory, inventory-management

I need your help(s). I am currently working on my thesis topic proposal and I am planning to propose an inventory management system with analytics. I am asked by my thesis adviser to think what any other features can I add to my topic?In short , what's new with the inventory system I am going to develop? Any Suggestion? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: So are you wanting to know what features to include in the inventory management system?

Comment: New Features so the panelist will approve my topic. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at existing inventory management solutions:

Sage:
http://www.sage.co.uk/software-and-services/business-management-solutions/sage-x3/functionality#link6

Microsoft Dynamics:
http://www.xperienceitsolutions.co.uk/MicrosoftNAV/NAVSupplyChain/InventoryManagement/

These are both industry leading stock management and inventory solutions. Research these and it will give you an idea of what feautres to include.

Examples of features could be:

- Multiple warehouses
- Stock transfer quantity
- Stock knock off

The next obvious thing would be to link the inventory to the sales and purchases so you can see what items have been sold historically and what items you need to reorder.

Comment: Thank you so much!